# Difference between v-model and v-bind on Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-directives

I'm learning Vue with an online course and the instructor gave me an exercise to make an input text with a default value.

I completed it using `v-model` but, the instructor chose `v-bind:value`, and I don't understand why.

Can someone give me a simple explanation about the difference between these two and when it's better use each one?

Comment: `v-model` is used mainly for input and form bidning, so use it when you dealing with various input types.`v-bind` directive allow you to produce some dynamic value by typing some JS expression that in most cases depends on the data from data model - so think about v-bind as directive that you should use when you want deal with some dynamic things.

Comment: In some case you can use each of them. Sometimes not, for example: `<div v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }"></div>` - you can't bind html attribute using model, you should use `v-bind` directive.
For form's elements you will want to use `v-model` directive -  "it automatically picks the correct way to update the element based on the input type."

Comment: @Alexander The phrase "bind HTML attribute" helped me think about this better. It would be good to see you weigh in on this with a more complete answer about what's actually happening with these two constructs.

Comment: @Alexander Esp in the context of component `data` and `props`...

Answer (score 679):

From **[here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)** -
Remember:

```html
<input v-model="something">
```

is essentially the same as:

```html
<input
    v-bind:value="something"
    v-on:input="something = $event.target.value"
>
```

or (shorthand syntax):

```html
<input
    :value="something"
    @input="something = $event.target.value"
>
```

So `v-model` is a **two-way binding for form inputs**. It combines `v-bind`, which ***brings a js value*** into the markup and `v-on:input` to ***update the js value***. The js value must be present in your `data`, or in an `inject`.

Use `v-model` when you can. Use `v-bind`/`v-on` when you must :-) I hope your answer was accepted.

`v-model` [works with all the basic HTML input types](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) (text, textarea, number, radio, checkbox, select). You can use `v-model` with `input type=date` if your model stores dates as ISO strings (yyyy-mm-dd). If you want to use date objects in your model (a good idea as soon as you're going to manipulate or format them), [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46845523/1585345).

`v-model` has some extra smarts that it's good to be aware of. If you're using an IME ( lots of mobile keyboards, or Chinese/Japanese/Korean ), v-model will not update until a word is complete (a space is entered or the user leaves the field). `v-input` will fire much more frequently.

`v-model` also has modifiers `.lazy`, `.trim`, `.number`, covered in [the doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html).

Comment: 'Use v-model when you can. Use v-bind/v-on when you must'. Great summary! Thank you very much!

Comment: What's the difference between `v-model` and `v-bind:xxx.sync`?

Comment: @ElMac v-model is a two-way binding between a Vue component and a javascript model. The source (the model side of the binding) is declared in the data of the Vue component. Like this, Vue lets you extract state from your components, then modify this state directly from the component. It's a simple pattern for state management that is a hallmark of Vue (difficult/hidden/impossible/discouraged in Angular and React). v-bind:xxx.sync is a two-way binding between a Vue component and its parent]. The state stays encapsulated. It 'belongs' to the parent. This is not necessarily better!

Comment: "is essentially the same as" - WRONG. When you use `v-model` it "touches" the object and all inputs will be redrawn, even the ones that use `v-bind`. When you assign `something = $event.target.value` - it won't redraw

Comment: @Alex how do you know this? What practical difference does it make? When you say "all inputs", you use v-model on one input at a time.

Comment: @bbsimonbb I bumped into this many times. To emulate v-model behavior in full it should be `Vue.set(obj, 'something', $event.target.value)` so you don't just update a property, but trigger vue's reactivity too.

Comment: Vue's reactivity is triggered with `=`. `Vue.set()` is useful in specific cases like arrays, but so long as you assign properties, and take care to not overwrite the root of a watched object, `=`works just fine.

Answer (score 96):

In simple words:

`v-model`: **two way bindings**

if you change input value, the bound data will be changed and vice versa.

`v-bind:value` **one way binding**

You can change input value by changing bound data but you can't change bound data by changing input value through the element_.

Check out this simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/gs0kphvc/

Comment: ' if you change input value, the bound data will be changed and vice versa. ' - can't understand the 'vice versa' part even from the fiddle example. can you explain it ?

Comment: if you change input value through the element, the bound data will be changed and also if you change bound data through for example Vue APIs your input element value would change.

Comment: how to change bound data through Vue API ?

Comment: In fiddle example, say we have a method that changes data_source like this `this.data_source = 'Some new value'`

Comment: by `data_source`, you mean the HTML injected in DOM from `input`, right ?

Comment: v-bind:value and v-model can't be used on same input element.

Comment: @Istiaque Ahmed, when you change the data_source here, in the Vue instance - data: { data_source: 'dsadsadasdsa', }, this will be applied to the v-model="data_source", and vice versa, because data_source in the template is bound to the data_source in the Vue instance via v-model. This is the two-way data binding in action. See this fiddle and try it. https://jsfiddle.net/opa4q7x1/

Answer (score 9):

`v-model` is for two way bindings means: if you change input value, the bound data will be changed and vice versa. But `v-bind:value` is called one way binding that means: you can change input value by changing bound data but you can't change bound data by changing input value through the element.

`v-model` is intended to be used with form elements. It allows you to tie the form element (e.g. a text input) with the data object in your Vue instance.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/jamesbrndwgn/j2yb9zt1/1/

`v-bind` is intended to be used with components to create custom props. This allows you to pass data to a component. As the prop is reactive, if the data that’s passed to the component changes then the component will reflect this change

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/jamesbrndwgn/ws5kad1c/3/

Answer (score 7):

**v-model**
it is two way data binding, it is used to bind html input element when you change input value then bounded data will be change.

***v-model is used only for HTML input elements***

```
ex: <input type="text" v-model="name" >
```

**v-bind**
it is one way data binding,means you can only bind data to input element but can't change bounded data changing input element.
**v-bind is used to bind html attribute**
ex: 
`<input type="text" v-bind:class="abc" v-bind:value="">`

```
<a v-bind:href="home/abc" > click me </a>
```

Comment: 'v-model it is two way data binding' : what are those 2 ways specifically ?

Answer (score 2):

There are cases where you don't want to use `v-model`. If you have two inputs, and each depend on each other, you might have circular referential issues. Common use cases is if you're building an accounting calculator.

In these cases, it's not a good idea to use either watchers or computed properties.

Instead, take your `v-model` and split it as above answer indicates

```
<input
   :value="something"
   @input="something = $event.target.value"
>
```

In practice, if you are decoupling your logic this way, you'll probably be calling a method.

This is what it would look like in a real world scenario:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input :value="extendedCost" @input="_onInputExtendedCost" />
  <p> {{ extendedCost }}
</div>

<script>
  var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: function(){
      return {
        extendedCost: 0,
      }
    },
    methods: {
      _onInputExtendedCost: function($event) {
        this.extendedCost = parseInt($event.target.value);
        // Go update other inputs here
    }
  }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**VUE JS**
Problem =>   **Unnecessary value binding used alongside v-model. It will interfere with v-model's behavior.**

```
<input v-model="signup.password" id="password" name="password" type="password" required="" value="">
```

It is problem.

Solve:

```
<input v-model="signup.password" id="password" name="password" type="password" required="">
```

Value cannot be used here if `v-model` is used. Removing the value will solve the problem