# In Vue, how do I bind a date object to a date input ? (v-model doesn't work)

Tags: vue.js

```
// This doesn't work
<input type='date' v-model='store.myDateObject'>
```

How can I bind a date input to a date object in my store?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want your dates as midnight UTC date objects, do this...

```
<input type='date'
    :value='store.myDate.toJSON().substring(0,10)'
    @input='store.myDate = new Date($event.target.value)'
>
```

Comment: I had to use $event instead of $event.target.value in @input with Vue 2.6.10, Chrome 73.0.3683.103, and Edge 42.17134.1.0. I'm not sure if a change in Vue itself or in the browsers caused this, but I can't say I'm confident this will work in every browser.