# how to set the default date of the day in vue js

Tags: javascript, html, date, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to set the date of the day by default in my datepicker.

code:

```
<template lang="html">
  <input type="date" v-model="date">
</template>
<script lang="js">
export default {
name: 'component',
props: [],
mounted() {

},
data() {
  return {
    // date: new Date().toJSON.split('T')[0],
    date: new Date(),
  }
},
methods: {

},
computed: {

},
               }
</script>
```

it does not work unfortunately, I was told about moment js but I do not know how we use it

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`v-model` on a Date input works with a string in yyyy-MM-dd format. If you're happy to have strings in your model, not date objects, then just put your default date string in the date variable, like this.

```
date : new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10)
```

Here's a running example. A name has been changed to avoid having variable names close to reserved keywords!

```js
vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vueRoot',
  data: { myDate : new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10) }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div  id='vueRoot'>
    <input type='date' v-model='myDate'>
    <br>
    {{myDate}}
</div>
```

Of course, you may want to have dates as date objects in your model, if you want to format or compare them. In that case, you should avoid v-model and code the two sides of your binding separately, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46845523/1585345).

Comment: That was exaclty what I need.

Answer (score 1):

`v-model` binding

```
<datepicker v-model="state.date" name="uniquename"></datepicker>
```

Emits events

```
<datepicker 
    @selected="doSomethingInParentComponentFunction" 
    @opened="datepickerOpenedFunction"
    @closed="datepickerClosedFunction"
>
</datepicker>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, to be a good answer it needs to explain why.