# Why Vuejs is not updating model until input loses focus

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

My app works with the following kind of data:
There are companies which each have a list of datapoints.
Each datapoint has a single type and each company can only have one datapoint of each type.

```
+Company_1  
|  
|--Datapoint_1 : type_1  
|--Datapoint_2 : type_2  
|--Datapoint_3 : type_3  
|  
|  
+Company_2  
|  
|--Datapoint_4 : type_3  
|--Datapoint_5 : type_2  
|  
|+Company_3  
|  
|--Datapoint_6 : type_2  
...  
...
```

In total there are about 1000 datapoints and 20 companies.
The app calculates analytics based on these datapoints and the goal is to allow users to manipulate these datapoints in order to see what the results would look like in a given scenario.
At any given moment, there is a "selected_company" and "selected_type" and based on these two selections, the correct datapoint should be chosen for manipulation.

I realised that if the "companies" variable, and "datapoints" property were arrays, a search would have to be done on all the items in order to find the correct ones.
I therefore chose to make them objects :

```
companies = {
  '1' : {
    name : 'Company_1',
    datapoints : {
      'type_1' : { ... },
      'type_2' : { ... },
      'type_3' : { ... }
    }
  },
  '2' : {...},
  '3' : {...},
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Problem:

I have a 'datapoint' component, that I am passing datapoints as props :

```
<datum-comp :datum="companies[selected_company].datapoints[selected_type]"></datum-comp>
```

Within this component, I have an input that is used to manipulate the score property of the datapoint:

```
<input v-model.number="datum.score" class="form-control">
```

However, this input is exhibiting very strange behaviour. As I type into the input, the model is not immediately updated. Instead, Vue seems to be waiting for me to change focus from the input (onBlur) before updating the model.

[not updating until onblur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZvzL.gif)

Even more weird, is that when I make the datapoints property an array

```
companies = {
      '1' : {
        name : 'Company_1',
        datapoints : [
          { ... },
          { ... },
          { ... }
        ]
      },
```

and use a method to retrieve the datapoint (as opposed to directly passing it in), Vue functions the correct way!

```
<datum-comp :datum="getDatum(selected_company, selected_type)"></datum-comp>
```

(in js file:)

```
var app = new Vue({
    el : '#app',
    data:{...},
    methods:{
      getDatum: function(selected_company, selected_type){
          var datum = this.companies[selected_company].datapoints.find(function(elem){
            return elem.type == selected_type
          })
          return datun
        }
    }
  })
```

[updating correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMQQf.gif)

I need help understanding why Vue behaves like this under these circumstances as it has some serious implications for app performance.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the same behaviour also occur in Vue.js doc example https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html in the same browser? You might want to try `@input=""` and then call a function that does the update instead.

Answer (score 8):

`v-model` is mostly [syntax sugar for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44678583/1585345)...
`:value="modelValue" @input="modelValue = $event.target.value"`

As you say, it updates the model [oninput](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp), which works well most of the time.

If you want something else, it's very easy to do. Just change the update side to onkeypress, so...

```
<input  class="form-control
    :value="datum.score" 
    @keypress="datum.score = $event.target.value""
    @input="datum.score = $event.target.value""
>
```

The changes you're noticing when you change datapoints from an array to an object are likely due to the fact that Vue2 [cannot detect changes made in an array using array syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats) (square brackets). You need to use array methods (push, pop, splice, etc.) or Vue.set(). Like you say, this is not intuitive, but it's one of the very few traps in Vue2. It's due to limitations of javascript, and it's well covered in the doc.

Comment: Will that trigger if you drag data with the mouse into the field?

Comment: No, but just keep cumulating the events that you use until you get the behaviour you want. a combination of keypress and input should cover it. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yep. Separate issue. [Changes made to arrays using array syntax do not trigger reactivity](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats). This is a limitation of javascript and there are a couple of workarounds suggested. This is one of the very few traps in Vue, and it's well explained in the doc.