# Why do not render checkboxes with checked attribute true vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working an edit form, it happens that I have several options to choose, these options are obtained by ajax with axios and I assign them to the variable `permisos` of the component that later renders through a v-for, the checked elements I have them in a array `selected` that is assigned to the vue-model as follows

```
<div class="row">
  <div v-for="permiso in permisos" class="col-md-5 col-12 col-sm-5" >                       
      <input type="checkbox" :value="permiso.id" 
         class="form-control" :id=permiso.id
         v-model="selected" :checked=selected.filter(e => e.id === permiso.id).length > 0 > {{ permiso.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

later I make another ajax call to know what options I had before editing the item to know what options or checkbox I will assign the checked attribute, this is where I have problems do not check correctly.

```
axios.get('api/allpermisos')
  .then(response =>{
    this.permisos = response.data; //dataok
  })
if(this.action===2){
  axios.get('api/allpermisos/'+ this.dataobject.id)
    .then(response =>{
        this.selected = response.data;//data ok
    })
}
```

How can I do so that when I get the ajax call from the options already selected, the attribute checked is assigned automatically and those that are not, are not assigned. try with includes but I do not have the desired result?

The code works correctly if I remove the v-model. Why is this happening?

```
<input type="checkbox" :value="permiso.id" class="form-control" 
        :id=permiso.id  :checked=selected.filter(e => e.id === permiso.id).length > 0 > {{ permiso.name}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need both v-model and :checked. [v-model is a two way binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44678583/1585345).

https://jsfiddle.net/bbsimonbb/eywraw8t/15613/

```
<div v-for="permiso in permisos" class="col-md-5 col-12 col-sm-5" >                       
    <input type="checkbox" :value="permiso.id" 
       class="form-control" :id=permiso.id
       v-model="selected"> {{ permiso.name}}
</div>
```

Consider creating a component for your input. Form inputs inside a v-for rapidly gets complicated.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification, something told me that there was something left over. Now a question is necessary to create components only for the components that are in the v-for or for all the input type select, etc?

Comment: Yup. Now that we got rid of that :checked expression, I think it's just fine like that, and would likely be harder to understand if it was in a component. Don't worry.

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep their ids in "selected" array, you are probably keeping whole objects which didn't work from what I checked.

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="row">
    <div v-for="permiso in permisos" class="col-md-5 col-12 col-sm-5" >                       
        <input type="checkbox" :value="permiso.id" 
           class="form-control" :id=permiso.id
           v-model="selected" :checked=selected.includes(permiso.id)> {{ permiso.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Vue:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      selected: [2, 4],
      permisos: [{id: 1, name: "test1"}, {id: 2, name: "test2"}, {id: 3, name: "test3"}, {id: 4, name: "test4"}]
    }
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/15555/

This works.
If you are getting object array as response, you could do this:

```
this.selected = response.data.map(obj => obj.id);
```