# How to bind input field value without V-model?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, setinterval

In my Vue app, I have a timer and a text field.

When I try to decrease the remaining seconds, the changes I make in the field keep disappearing. The timer and the field are completely unrelated.

Here's a simple demo, write anything to the field:

https://codepen.io/basabence/pen/jObwqgL

```
<div id="app">
    <span>Time: {{remaining_time}}</span><br>
    <input :value="step_answer" type="text">
</div>

app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    remaining_seconds: 60,
    step_answer: "asdasd",
  },
  created: function (){
    setInterval(()=>{
      this.remaining_seconds--
    },1000);
  }
})
```

Interestingly if I change the `:value` to v-model, it works fine - but I don't want to bind this field two-way... Have any of you met this behaviour before?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You get this behavior because `data` is a `reactive` object. When you bind the `value` with `step_answer`, you create one-way binding `data -> component`, which means `step_answer` is the master.

To achieve `Two-way` binding without `v-model` you need to capture `@input event` and append it or assign `step_master` with the `new value`.

```
<input
  v-bind:value="step_answer"
  v-on:input="step_answer = $event.target.value">
```

Full example :

```
<div id="app">
    <span>Time: {{remaining_seconds}}</span><br>
    <input
  v-bind:value="step_answer"
  v-on:input="appendValue($event)">
</div>


app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    remaining_seconds: 60,
    step_answer: "asdasd",
  },

  created: function (){
    setInterval(()=>{
      this.remaining_seconds--
    },1000);
  },
  methods:{
    appendValue(e){
      this.step_answer=e.target.value;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: It just hit me: that's what v-once is created for !! 
Thanks for the breadcrumbs, I was stuck with this for hours...

Answer (score 1):

`:value`, a one way binding, will never let the input from your keyboard update the state of the component. That is why v-model exists. Check out [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42260233) for more details.

Comment: But I don't want the model to be updated... I just need the variable in the value :)

Comment: I need the value as well; I'm trying to avoid any binding because that invokes DOM re-render (which invokes other render logic).