# Input v-checkbox checked by default

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I Attempting to create a "v-checkbox" entry marked by default **without using v-model directive**.

In the official documentation for this Vuetify component I can't find the information on how to do this.

I tried to place this code but it doesn't work

```
<v-checkbox checked="true"></v-checkbox>
<v-checkbox  checked="checked"></v-checkbox>
<v-checkbox  checked></v-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do this is by setting `input-value="true"`, as described in the [API docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-checkbox/#props).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-checkbox label="Foo" input-value="1"></v-checkbox>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: This one worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `:value="checked"` where `checked` is a boolean variable. `value` is a one-way binding while `v-model` is a two-way binding. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54226898/9183405):

> **v-bind:value (or :value)** is called one way binding that means: you can change input value by changing bound data but you can't change bound data by changing input value through the element.
>
> **v-model** is for two way bindings means: *if you change input value, the bound data will be changed and vice versa*.

```html
<template>
  ...
  <v-checkbox :value="checked"/>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        checked: true,
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This one does not work for me.