# Non V-bind part of the V-Model

Tags: vue.js

As we know v-model is two way binding. Which means it's combination of V-bind and maybe another attribute which I'm looking for and it updates the data. I have a input which it's value is sometimes custom and sometimes should be read from config based on another parameters.
What I need is an input with a v-bind:value/:value and another for update. I know I can do it with @change and a custom method But I'm looking for something easy, Bottom line is I want V-model without doing v-bind ! Thank You

EDIT: I did it with two input using v-if .

```
<input type="number" class="item-input"  v-if="setting.keto_program=='custom'" id="protein_per_kilo" v-model="setting.keto_program_protein_density">
 <input type="number" class="item-input"  v-else disabled id="protein_per_kilo" :value="config.keto_programs[setting.keto_program].protein_density">
```

Anyway doing this using just one input feels better. Thanks

Comment: imo, if its a bunch of fields all based upon `setting.keto_program` being custom, make a component and pass 2 props, `:editable="setting.keto_program === 'custom'"`, `:model="setting.keto_program === 'custom' ? setting : config.keto_programs[setting.keto_program]"` then its done on component level so your only have one set of fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can use `computed` hook.

```
computed:{
  yourVariable(){
    return someVariable/computation
  }  
}
```

you can use `yourVariable` inside your code that will act like v-model without doing v-bind.

`yourVariable` will be updated as soon as the variables of the return statement of this be changed or updated

Edited:

**part of v-model for input tag**

```
<input
   v-bind:value="variable"
   v-on:input="variable = $event.target.value"
>
```

or

```
<input
   :value="variable"
   @input="variable = $event.target.value"
>
```

found this via
[Vue.js—Difference between v-model and v-bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260233/vue-js-difference-between-v-model-and-v-bind)

Comment: Thank You, But this is not what I'm looking for

Comment: Can you elaborate it ? may be you can use conditions in your computed property based on your "sometimes custom and sometimes should be read from config based on other parameters"

Comment: I have updated the answer according to your requirement. may be it's what you are looking for. may be it will help for your logic