# Vue js dynamic inputs value affecting all other inputs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input

So I'm bringing in data from a CMS which is dynamically creating a title, a size and an input field which the user will be able to change.

When I increase the input value (1, 2, 3, 4 etc) the value changes in all inputs.

I need to take the number of individual inputs and do something with it.

I can *kind of* get this to work if I have my input type set to number but I want to keep it set to text so I can use custom increment and decrement buttons.
As I said the buttons and the counter works but values clone to every input.  I'm sure it's something to do with the increaseQty and decreaseQty functions..

I'm **very** new to Vue so be gentle.
Thanks a million - Code below

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="step2items0" class="inventory">
      <div class="inner-wrap">
        <label>Choose Your {{ selected }} Items</label>
      </div>
      <div id="tabBtns" class="hr">
        <div class="inner-wrap mobile-center">
          <div v-for="(tab, index) in tabs" :key="index" @click="selectTab(tab)" class="tab" :class="selected_tab == tab ? 'selected' : ''" >
            {{ tab }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="items-wrap">
        <div class="item" v-for="(row, index) in items" :key="index">
          <span class="lbl">{{ row.item_title }}</span>

          <span class="input-wrap" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
            <input type="text" name="item_m3" class="number" :value="row.item_m3"/>
            <small>Item M3</small>
          </span>


          <span class="input-wrap">
            <i id="decreaseQty" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-caret-left prev-btn" @click="decreaseQty"></i>

            <input id="quantity" type="text" class="number" :value="quantity"/>

            <i id="increaseQty" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-caret-right nxt-btn" @click="increaseQty"></i>
          </span>

          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>






<script>
module.exports = {
  props: ["selected", "content", "value"],

  data: function () {
    return {
      tabs: [],
      selected_tab: "",
      items: [],
      quantity: 0,
    };
  },
  computed: {

  },

  methods: {
    //

    increaseQty() {
      this.quantity++;
      console.log("AMOUNT -", this.quantity);
    },
    decreaseQty() {
      if (this.quantity === 0) {
        alert("Negative quantity not allowed");
      } else {
        this.quantity--;
        console.log("AMOUNT -", this.quantity);
      }
    },
    //

    selectTab: function (value) {
      console.log("TAB: ", value);
      this.selected_tab = value;
      const { content } = this;
      let { items } = this;

      content.forEach(function (row) {
        if (row.room_name == value) {
          items = row.item;

          items.forEach(function (row) {
            item_title = row.item_title;
            item_m3 = row.item_m3;
            console.log(" - ", item_title, " - ", item_m3);
          });
        }
      });

      this.items = items;
    },
  },
  mounted: function () {
    const { selected, content, tabs } = this;
    let { selected_tab, items } = this;

    console.log("SELECTED: ", selected);

    if (selected === "Household") {
      content.forEach(function (row) {
        if (row.is_household == true) {
          tabs.push(row.room_name);

          if (selected_tab == "") {
            selected_tab = row.room_name;

            items = row.item;

            items.forEach(function (row) {
              item_title = row.item_title;
              item_m3 = row.item_m3;
              console.log(" - ", item_title, " - ", item_m3);
            });
          }
        }
      });
    } else if (selected === "Business") {
      content.forEach(function (row) {
        if (row.is_business == true) {
          tabs.push(row.room_name);

          if (selected_tab == "") {
            selected_tab = row.room_name;

            items = row.item;

            items.forEach(function (row) {
              item_title = row.item_title;
              item_m3 = row.item_m3;
              console.log(row.room_name, " - ", item_title, " - ", item_m3);
            });
          }
        }
      });
    }

    this.selected_tab = selected_tab;
    this.items = items;
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

[Input increment is affecting all inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc2kJ.png)

[image: ID stay the same no matter what button is clicked on any item]

Comment: you should do `@click="increaseQty(row)"`, then inside increaseQty, it has a param `increaseQty(row){}`, then inside the func, you do `this.$set(row, 'qty', typeof row.qty !== 'undefined' ? row.qty+1 : 1)` `:value="quantity"` then should be `:value="row.qty || 0"`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone that has done the job thank you!  Would you mind explaining why it works?  I know I had to pass something into the function but I would never have got the rest

Comment: each item in `items` call it `row`, is an object, all its doing is passing the specific object to the function to be manipulated, the `this.$set`, is used because if a property doesn't exist already on the object then it's not reactive.

Answer (score 1):

You can get individual values inside the `v-for` by storing the values in an array.

```
data: {
    items: [],
    itemValues: [],
  },
```

And use `v-model` to bind the input (you are using `v-bind:value`, not `v-model`). You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260233/vue-js-difference-between-v-model-and-v-bind) to learn the difference.

```
<div class="item" v-for="(row, index) in items" :key="index">
    <input type="text" v-model="itemValues[index]">
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jariway/jxv0k4y3/62/

Comment: The problem I'm having is when I click the increment and decrement buttons I can see in the console that no matter which buttons I click it's only giving me the ID of the last one.   I've updated the post to show

Comment: @SamDonaghy-Bell Then you need to pass the index to the onClick listener. Check the updated fiddle in the answer. This way you can increase the values individually.

Comment: Thank you.  I've got it working with Lawrence's answer but I'm sure I'll be back in here once I try and add more function to it and break things entirely!  haha.