# why my wysiwyg editor works so slow in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, wysiwyg

I decided to use wysiwyg editor on my page. I'm using simple two-way data binding via `v-model="text"` and simpy output `<div v-html="text"></div>`. I'm beginner in vuejs, but I need to ask this question:
Why this is running so slow? It doesn't matter if it is `quill editor/medium-editor/vueditor`.

Every time I type new letter, the delay is very noticable and user experience is poor. My console gives a messages:

```
[Violation] 'message' handler took 199ms
```

and sometimes

```
[Violation] Added synchronous DOM mutation listener to a 'DOMNodeInserted'
event. Consider using MutationObserver to make the page more responsive.
```

It's even worse if I bind it into computed property (delays up to 250ms)- which I will need to do soon. And I also need to do two-way data binding in my case.

What am I doing wrong? How could I speed up typing process annd improve typing experience? My component has about 1,5k lines. Could that be the case?

edit:

I've break my 1,5k lines code component into separate part for editing and this already improve web speed from about 250 ms to 50-60ms, but wysiwyg editor and two-way data binding remain still noticebly slow.

edit2: code (using vuetify)

Example1 (mid-fast):

```
<v-text-field
  label="Write something"
  v-model="text"
  counter
  max="120"
  rows="3"
  full-width
  multi-line
  single-line
></v-text-field>
<div  v-html="textComputed"></div>

data () {
  return {
    text: ''
  }
},
computed: {
  textComputed() {
  //using computed to add <li> tags
    return '<li>' + this.text.replace(/\n/g, "<br /></li><li>") + '</li>'
  }
}
```

Example2 (slow):

```
<quill-editor 
      v-model="text"
      :options="editorOptionProTemplate"
      >
</quill-editor>
<div  v-html="textComputed"></div>

data () {
  return {
    text: ''
  }
},
computed: {
  //using computed for many variants for styling output in web (here just adding <b> tag)
  textComputed() {
    return '<b>' + this.text + '</b>'
  }
}
```

Comment: *My component has about 1,5k lines. Could that be the case?* It could. Ultimately, though, we have to see some code to help you.

Comment: @acdcjunior actually - it's SPA, so maybe (?) if I will make separate component only for my data-binding editing - it will run faster? I was curious if this kind of delay is something common

Comment: It's not. But if the text is so big, maybe you couldn't avoid it (formatting a large thing will take a large time, anyway). Caching could help, but this seems like something very specific to your app, so it's unclear how vue could help you achieve that more easily.

Comment: my app isn't special in any kind - just normal SPA based on vuetify. But the component is so large, so if vue rerender the page - this cause so much delay

Comment: Do you need the data item to update on every keystroke? Maybe try `v-model.lazy`

Comment: @RoyJ this might be a good idea, but the user experience on my site is better without lazy parametr... but I will try it

Comment: Maybe breaking the text in (data) parts, and re-rendering them only...

Comment: [debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199956/how-to-implement-debounce-in-vue2) could be helpful.

Comment: @acdcjunior what do you mean by breaking the text? Making the separate component with every wysiwyg editor and text output?

Comment: @RoyJ Thanks, I didn't know what it is, should look at this.
I edited my question - with new improvement

Comment: I added code to my question

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/92r4C/113/)? It's not Vue, but it has some interesting code in how it does updates.

Comment: @RoyJ thanks, I'll look at this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best friend here is [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce). You can v-model a computed whose `set` function debounces the setting of the value:

```
debounceText: {
  get() { return this.text; },
  set: _.debounce(function(newValue) {
    this.text = newValue;
  }, 100)
},
```

You will see a little lag in the updating of the HTML output, but much less lag in the editor as you type. I have made [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5sv1thc/) to demonstrate. Copy a bunch of text in and see how it handles for you.

Comment: Thank you! Can't wait to find the time to check it :)