# Typing slow in text input or textarea on large module in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a large form that has lots of input text. When I am typing fast on the input it slow to render.

```
<b-form-input v-model="paymentItems.tierStepUPYear" type="text"></b-form-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that Vue is firing actions that contain the entire text every time you press a key.  You could slow down these actions by using "debounce".

Debounce is described here: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce

This idea is suggested here, and might also apply to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49011172