# Pass an argument to method's function with debounce - vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, debouncing

Template:

```
<input @keyup="fetchData(0)" v-model="name">
```

Method:

```
  methods: {
    fetchData: _.debounce(function (value) {
      console.log('Argument is: ' + value)
      axios.get(globalConfig.ORDERS_URL, {
        params: {
          limit: this.perPage,
          offset: (this.currentPage - 1) * this.perPage,
          name: this.name,
          phone: this.phone,
          from_date: this.dateOne,
          to_date: this.dateTwo
        }
      })
        .then((resp) => {
          this.req = resp.data
          // console.log(resp)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    }, 500)
  }
```

Calling `fetchData` with argument 0 - `fetchData(0)`, but it won't pass because i'm using `_.debounce`. Console log shows "undefined"

How to correctly pass an argument?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49780382/5648253

Comment: As far i understand, `created()` fires when a page loads, but my `fetchData` fires not only during the initial page load, but also when a user applies filters.

Comment: Why do you need that argument `0`?

Answer (score 3):

Install [debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce) package.

Import it in your component:

```
import debounce from 'debounce'
```

Update template by removing `0` from `fetchData`:

```
<input @input="fetchData" v-model="name">
```

I changed the event to `@input` but it will work with `@keyup` too.

Then change your function to:

```
fetchData: debounce(e => {
  console.log('Input argument is: ' + e.target.value);
}, 500)
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/8x6rj4lnzl (App.vue)

Comment: It's work but how to access data in arrow function? 'this' is not work inside that fetchData function.

Comment: You can also use usual function with context to get access to 'this'. Something like debounce (function(e){ this.$emit('inputChanged', e) }, 500)

Answer (score 3):

The following code has not been checked, but I wanted to explain more about debounce and how "v-on" or "@" events in Vue work.

On your `<input>` tag you can use `<input @input="fetchData" v-model="name">` as @dziraf explained, and do a bunch of extra work for the extra variable. OR ...

**TO SEND ARGUMENTS**, you simply have to explicitly include the "EVENT" variable first (in Vue.js events it's name is $event), then any you choose to add:

```
<input 
  @input="fetchData($event, 'Custom Values', customVariables)"
  v-model="name"
>
```

Now you have access to all variables sent to "your function" or the "debounced function" (which is simply a wrapped version of any function you send it):

```
methods: {
  fetchData: 
    _.debounce( 
      (e, customVariable1=undefined, customVariable2=undefined) => {
        console.log('Input argument is: ' + e.target.value);
      }, 500),
...
```

**HINT:** The "=undefined" in the 2 customVariables is used to make them optional.

**WARNING:** Be CAREFUL if you will implement multiple instances of this component on a single page, then using your debounce function in `methods:` is NOT recommended due to some encapsulation issues during some initial Vue Lifecycle hooks. Also I believe you cannot call the `.cancel()` method if needed when you some other user interaction and stop the function before the delay is over.

It's recommended to save the function to a variable in the `created()` lifecycle rather than a `method:`:

```
created() {
  this.fetchData = _.debounce( 
    (e, customVariable1=undefined, customVariable2=undefined) => {
      console.log('Input argument is: ' + e.target.value);
    }, 500);
}
```

Now, **you can call the `.cancel()` method** to properly garbage collect:

```
beforeDestroy() {
  this.fetchData.cancel();
}
```

Or, **have a "Cancel" button** or call from another UI element:

```
<button @click="fetchData.cancel();">Cancel the Request</button>
```

You can try this code to see the minor differences in the encapsulation:

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>Using debounce as a data() variable declared in created():</div>
  <create-change ref="counter1"></create-change>
  <create-change ref="counter2"></create-change>
  <create-change ref="counter3"></create-change>
  <create-change ref="counter4"></create-change>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div>Using debounce as a Method:</div>
  <method-change ref="counter5"></method-change>
  <method-change ref="counter6"></method-change>
  <method-change ref="counter7"></method-change>
  <method-change ref="counter8"></method-change>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
Vue.component('create-change', {

  template:
    `
      <button @click="changeContent($event,'any custom value')">
        Click to change my value: {{ i }}
      </button>
    `,

  data: function(){
    return { i: 0 };
  },

  created() {
   this.changeContent = _.debounce(function(e, val=0){
      if (val) { this.i = val } // or reference a method here
    }, 1000)
  },

});

Vue.component('method-change', {

  template: 
    `
      <button @click="changeContent($event,'any custom value')">
        Click to change my value: {{ i }}
      </button>
    `,

  data: function(){
    return { i: 0 };
  },

  methods: {

    // WARNING: Can have encapsulation issues
   changeContent: _.debounce(function(e, val=0){
      if (val) { this.i = val }
    }, 1000),

  },

});


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted () {
    this.$refs.counter1.changeContent(null,1);
    this.$refs.counter2.changeContent(null,2);
    this.$refs.counter3.changeContent(null,3);
    this.$refs.counter4.changeContent(null,4);
    this.$refs.counter5.changeContent(null,5);
    this.$refs.counter6.changeContent(null,6);
    this.$refs.counter7.changeContent(null,7);
    this.$refs.counter8.changeContent(null,8);
  }
});
```

**CSS**

```
#app {
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for a solution, in general, here's a working version, I hope it will help save a minute to someone :)

```
// Lodash or any custom function debounce
import _ from 'lodash';

const template = `
   <input v-model="textInput">
`;

export default {
    template: template,
    data: () => {
        return {
            textInput: null
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        let vue = this;

        vue.debouncedApiPatch = _.debounce(vue.apiPatch, 500);

        vue.$watch('textInput', function (val) {
            vue.debouncedApiPatch('textInput', val);
        })
    },
    methods: {
        apiPatch: function (prop, val) {
            console.log(prop, val);
            // api async patch...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way according to the [official vue forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/lodash-debounce-not-working-when-placed-inside-a-method/86334/5)