# VueJs and Axios : Trigger after input with a delay + cancel previous

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

So on my website I have a input box

```
<SearchBox v-model="searchTerm"/>
```

Which I watch and call an url via `Axios`

```
watch: {
    searchTerm: function() {
      axios
      .get("https://robotic.buzz/skynet/search/" + searchTerm)
      .then(response => {
        // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
        this.results = response.data;
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e);
      });
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to delay the call and cancel previous ones? So if someone types something in, when they pause for 1 second, it then calls the server and doesn't call it for every letter they enter.

A simple 1-second delay would still queue up the calls.

Comment: You would usually use a debounce for something like that. Try taking a look at [lodashes debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce) function which you can [download from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce)

Comment: Looks a good solution how come you not posted it as one

Comment: In addition: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199956/how-to-implement-debounce-in-vue2

Comment: debounce fixed my issue perfectly

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `lazy` modifier as follows :

```
 <input type="text"  v-model.lazy="searchTerm" />
```

So when you leave the text field you could watch the data and call `axios`

```js
new Vue({

  el: '#app',
  data(){
  return{
  searchTerm:''
  }
  }
  ,
  watch: {
    searchTerm: function(val) {
    console.log(".")
      axios
      .get("https://robotic.buzz/skynet/search/" + val)
      .then(response => {
        // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
        console.log(response.data)
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Conversations -->

<div id="app">

<input type="text"  v-model.lazy="searchTerm" />

</div>
```