# Debounce an async method?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have:

```
async search() {
```

How can I implement lo dash's denounce? I've tried:

```
async search: _.debounce(function () {
```

But with no luck.

Comment: what is 'await' is in front of 'function'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<input type="text" @keypress="searchDebounce" />
```

```js
methods: {
    async search() {
        // get search result
    },
    searchDebounce: _.debounce(async function() {
        await this.search();
        // or you can move everything from search() to here, and delete this.search()
    }, 1000)
}
```

or [even better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49780382/12397250):

```js
data() {
  return {
    searchDebounce: null
  };
},
created() {
  this.searchDebounce = debounce(this.search, 1000);
}
```