# Awaiting till user finishes writing to input field in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a QR code creating page. I want my QR codes to be created dynamically by user input. But I don't want to instantly create a QR code. I want to wait my user to finish writing then after one second i will generate the QR code. So I have a template like below:

```
<div class="app">
    <qrcode-vue :value="genaratedQrCode"></qrcode-vue>
    <input type="text" v-model="qrCodeInput" />
</div>
```

And my script:

```
import QrcodeVue from 'qrcode.vue';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            genaratedQrCode: '',
            qrCodeInput: '',
            isInputFunctionRunning: false
        }
    },
    watch: {
        async qrCodeInput() {
            if (this.isInputFunctionRunning) {
                return;
            }

            this.isInputFunctionRunning = true;

            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));

            this.genaratedQrCode = this.qrCodeInput;

            this.isInputFunctionRunning = false;
        }
    }
    components: {
        QrcodeVue,
    },
}
```

Apparently the code is not working. It generated the QR code every one seconds. What I want is waiting till user finished, then updating after 1 seconds.

Comment: How can the browser tell if the user is really finished or is just thinking about what else to type?

Comment: It's not about thinking :) It is about finishing "writing". I don't care the reason why he/she stops writing. I just care if he/she stop or not.

Comment: What I'm saying is that it is not possible to detect that except via some explicit user action, like focusing on another element.

Comment: Hmm. I tried by using an on change method. But async await logic does not work. So is it really impossible or do you have any ideas to achieve it by using onchange? The watch method acts like on change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`.lazy`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#lazy) modifier :

```
<input type="text" v-model.lazy="qrCodeInput" />
```

If you want to wait some delay try this :

```
import QrcodeVue from 'qrcode.vue';

function debounce (fn, delay) {
  var timeoutID = null
  return function () {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID)
    var args = arguments
    var that = this
    timeoutID = setTimeout(function () {
      fn.apply(that, args)
    }, delay)
  }
}



export default {
    data() {
        return {
            genaratedQrCode: '',
            qrCodeInput: '',
            isInputFunctionRunning: false
        }
    },
    watch: {
        qrCodeInput:debounce(function() {
            if (this.isInputFunctionRunning) {
                return;
            }

            this.isInputFunctionRunning = true;

            this.genaratedQrCode = this.qrCodeInput;

            this.isInputFunctionRunning = false;
        },1000)
    }
    components: {
        QrcodeVue,
    },
}
```

This is based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53486112/8172857);

Comment: This kinda works. But it requires user to focus somewhere else.

Comment: This would work if the OP means that the user being "finished" indicates that by tabbing or clicking away from the input.

Comment: @Mansur please check the second suggestion