# I am using tiptap . How to make a preview from child component to parent component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, preview, tiptap

Below is my code.

**parent.vue**

```
<client-only>
  <EditorTiptap v-model="content" />
</client-only>
```

**tiptap.vue**

```
<div class="editor-panel">
  <editor-content :editor="editor" />
</div>
```

and

```
computed: {
  html () {
    if (!this.editor) return ''
    return this.editor.getHTML()
  },
}
```

In such a structure, how can I send the content input value of the child component to the parent component?

In order to implement the preview function in the parent component, the content of the child component must be fetched in real time.

I couldn't find a way to do anything with the html of computed .

Please tell me how to implement editor input of child component (tiptap.vue) as preview in parent component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property) to your `html` computed property to `$emit` its content to parent.

```js
watch: {
    html: function (val) {
      this.$emit('onHtmlChanged', html)
    },
}
```

Then your parent can listen to `@onHtmlChanged` :

```html
<client-only>
  <EditorTiptap v-model="content" @onHtmlChanged="doSomething" />
</client-only>
```

NOTE : It might be recommended that you [debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199956/how-to-implement-debounce-in-vue2) your event to prevent emitting a change at each keystroke

Comment: The problem I had been struggling with in two days was solved at once.

This is the answer that beat my Googling time. thank you.