# Input delay in vue-select

Tags: vue.js, vue-select

Using [vue-select](https://vue-select.org/) I'm searching for a way to add a delay on input so that a ajax-search-request is send after the user has paused the input for e.g. 500ms.

How can I archive this?
In the documentation I can't find any option for that.

In my solution I have a custom ajax-filter:

```html
<vSelect
        class="my-select"
        @search="fetchOptions"
        :filterable="false"
        :options="options"
        label="name"
        v-model="selectedVal"
        :disabled="disabled"
        :reduce="(result) => result.id"
    >
```

Comment: Would this help? <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199956/how-to-implement-debounce-in-vue2>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with adding `lodash.debouncer`.
For interest, following my solution:

```html
 <vSelect
        class="my-select"
        @search="loadDebouncer"
        :filterable="false"
        :options="options"
        label="myLabel"
        v-model="selectedVal"
        :disabled="disabled"
    >
```

```js
import { Component, Vue, Prop, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

@Component
export default class MySelect extends Vue{
    public loadDebouncer = debounce((searchString, loading) => this.fetchOptions(searchString, loading), 500);

    public async fetchOptions(searchString: string, loading:any){
        //Load my list
    }
}
```